# Getting a rigidbody to stick to a moving object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get my character to stick to objects when a button is pressed. I have gotten it to work on stationary objects. However, when an object is moving my character will slide around the object and eventually be flung of

The current code I have for sticking to objects is

```
        if (leftTriggerPressed && CanStick)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero; // Stop all current movement

          
            Vector2 stickForce = -surfaceNormal * 10f;
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.ClampMagnitude(stickForce, maxStickForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
```

where CanStick is set to true when my character is colliding with an object it is eligible to stick to

Is there a way to allow my character to stick to a moving object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are moveing your player by applying force to it.

Have you tried getting the object velocity at every frame and applying that velocity to your player RB instead?

you might be able to do this by setting the player RB to `kinematic` temporarily (while sticking).

also try to do this in the `fixedUpdate()` function.

let us know the result.

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested and have implemented code to
get collision.relativeVelocity within the OnCollisionStay2D
change the characters body type to kinematic (what is changed back with the oncollisionexit)
setting rb.velocity to the collision.relativeVelocity

however this is causing my character to be flung towards the ground when i attempt to stick to anything

Comment: You should use the absolute velocity or world space velocity(I don't remember the exact name). RelativeVelocity is the velocity compared to that objects orientation. Thats why its going to wrong direction.